# Extract user defined Resource from exe using only php

Tags: c#, php, windows, resources, exe

I have to extract a user defined resource from different exe and dll files. The resource contains version information I need to save and be able to display later but the data is not saved in the standard version resource. The author of the files has written code to extract the needed data but the source code is written in C#.  I have the source code from the original author for extracting the needed resource but I cannot figure out how to replicate the process in PHP.

Here is the C# code used for extracting the needed information from the resource:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    System.IntPtr moduleHandle = LoadLibraryEx(@"C:\examplefile.exe", IntPtr.Zero, LoadLibraryFlags.LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    if (moduleHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
        System.IntPtr hrsrc = FindResource(moduleHandle, (IntPtr)7777, "FILES");
        System.IntPtr hglob = LoadResource(moduleHandle, hrsrc);
        System.IntPtr rdata = LockResource(hglob);

        byte[] m_pBytes = new byte[6];
        Marshal.Copy(rdata, m_pBytes, 0, 6);

        int vv1 = m_pBytes[0];
        int vv2 = m_pBytes[1];
        int v1 = vv1 * 256 + vv2;
        int v2 = m_pBytes[2];
        int v3 = m_pBytes[3];
        vv1 = m_pBytes[4];
        vv2 = m_pBytes[5];
        int v4 = vv1 * 256 + vv2;
        FreeLibrary(moduleHandle);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}", v3, v2, v1, v4));


    }
}
```

I get stuck at the line:
System.IntPtr hrsrc = FindResource(moduleHandle, (IntPtr)7777, "FILES");

I cannot figure out exactly what is happening in this step. It appears that a pointer to the resource is being returned but I do not know how to replicate this in PHP. The Microsoft documentation for findResource isn't detailed enough for me to determine what's going on under the hood.

I have used ResourceHacker to view all resources in the file and a resource of type FILES is shown with an entry named 7777. I can see the binary data contained in the resource and see how it is used to produce the result in the code above. What I am missing is a way to search for and extract a resource by type using PHP.

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this and help me out.

A pure PHP solution would be best because our servers are Windows machines right now but we plan to switch to Linux so a solution that works on both platforms is ideal.